# Can a QListView have different vertical and horizontal spacing?

Tags: qt, pyside, qlistview

I am trying to make a QListView set to IconMode have a different spacing horizontally and vertically. Can this be achieved using this class?

Also, all of my icons have the same width but they change in height and I would like the view to adapt to these different sizes.

Comment: You can set a `gridSize` with different values for each dimension: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlistview.html#gridSize-prop
Or you can play with `flow` of the widget.
You can also use rows inside columns or vice-versa with positioners. http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qml-positioners.html#flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both can be done by `QStyledItemDelegate()`. In my example (pyqt5) `model.data()` returns the path of the icons, all icons have a width of 100. The return-value of `sizeHint()` depends on the height of the items icon and vertical- and horizontalSpacing:

```
class MyDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QItemDelegate.__init__(self)
        self.pen= QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(0,0,0))
        self.imageWidth = 100
        self.horizontalSpacing = 5
        self.verticalSpacing = 10

    def sizeHint(self, option, index):
        width = self.imageWidth + 2*self.horizontalSpacing
        height = QtGui.QImage(index.data()).height() + 2*self.verticalSpacing
        return QtCore.QSize(width, height)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        border = option.rect    # item.rect in the view
        image = QtGui.QImage(index.data())  # model.data() returns the path of the imagefile
        painter.save()
        painter.setPen(self.pen)
        painter.drawRect(border)
        painter.drawImage(QtCore.QPointF(border.x() + self.horizontalSpacing, border.top() + self.verticalSpacing), image)
        painter.restore()
```

set the delegate to the view by `setItemDelegate()`

looks like this:

[image: different rowHeight dependent on imageSize]